# Unique count of dataframe column values that excludes commas?

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine my dataframe is this:

```
               +         +
     Index     |    A    |    B
+--------------|---------|----------+
               |         |
1              |Y,Z      |    nan
               |         |
2              |Y,Z,X    |     2
               |         |
3              |Z        |     7
               |         |
4              |nan      |     1
               +         +
```

This dataframe is 10,000 lines long and contain many variations in Column A.

From Column A, how would I get the all unique returns by ignoring Commas (,)?

**From the 3 line data frame above, it would be:**

```
Z = 3
Y = 2
X = 1
```

I'm **not** looking for:

```
Y,Z = 1
Y,Z,X = 1
X = 1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```py
out = df['A'].str.split(',').explode().value_counts()
```

```
print(out)

Z    3
Y    2
X    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: There is an issue where it thinks spaces are okay?

Comment: @Sumit Don't get it. If there might be space after comma, you can try `out = df['A'].str.split(', *', regex=True).explode().value_counts()`.

Comment: Thanks @Ynjxsjmh, i used this version before doing the value counts and it worked for me :) your code seems more efficient as its one line 
`df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(' ', '')`

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
# Set up problem
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [['Y', 'Z'], ['Y','Z','X'], 'Z', np.NaN], 'B': [np.NaN,2,7,1]})

df.A.explode().value_counts()
```

Output

```
Z    3
Y    2
X    1
```

Comment: This works only if the A column contains actual list objects.  Otherwise have to do split/explode.

Comment: I followed this exactly but the output still assumes the "," part of the string. 
i.e. this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
df.A.str.split(",").explode().value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming strings, use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), combined with [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['A'].str.split(',').explode().value_counts()
```

output:

```
Z    3
Y    2
X    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Y,Z', 'Y,Z,X', 'Z', pd.NA], 'B': [pd.NA,2,7,1]})
```